# Diference between ./ and $ when importing modules into React project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

The author of [this project](https://github.com/GraphCMS/graphcms-sveltekit-portfolio-and-blog-starter/blob/main/src/routes/sitemap.xml.js) has imported a component using the following path:

`import { client } from '$lib/graphql-client'`

**My question is:**
What's the $ symbol do? What's the difference between it and something like: `import {client} from './lib/graphql-client'` ?

Comment: I am not React familiar but i suppose it will be something about relative and absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an alias. In this particular example it resolves to `./src/lib`.

See https://github.com/GraphCMS/graphcms-sveltekit-portfolio-and-blog-starter/blob/ca2b4175c312def64fb7965db860acd21f2ec707/svelte.config.js#L13

Answer (score 0):

That is a Path alias.

**Path aliases:**
with path aliases, you can declare aliases for certain paths.

As you see in [jsconfig](https://github.com/GraphCMS/graphcms-sveltekit-portfolio-and-blog-starter/blob/ca2b4175c312def64fb7965db860acd21f2ec707/jsconfig.json) inside `compilerOptions` you have:

**1- baseUrl**: telling compiler where to start resolving relative imports.

**2- paths:** defining your aliases for certain paths.

This is good for writing long and repeated paths.